# React Native, Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here's my `index.ios.js` constructor:

I want to make dynamic

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      testMessage : ''
    }
    this.testF()
  }

  testF(){
    this.setState({testMessage:'asdasd'});
    console.log(this.state)    
  }
```

Here's the error:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using `setState` inside the constructor. The state is just a regular object. By using the `setStte` the value updated and component re-rendered. When you call setState in the constructor, the component not mounted yet, so you got the warning. You can use `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` for using `setState`. Or change the state with `this.state` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a `componentDidMount` component life-cycle hook into your component's class. Like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      testMessage : ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     this.testF();
  }

  testF(){
    this.setState({testMessage:'asdasd'});
    console.log(this.state)    
  }
```

P.S.: Keep in mind that `setState` is asynchronous, so in some cases, whenever you try to log your component's state immediately after `setState`, you may not see the updated state yet.